# gnatmake linked failed on MacOS

Tags: ada

I was trying to compile an ada program using gnat but I got this error:

```
(base) alexandretrotel@MacBook-Pro TP1 % gnatmake Exercice6.adb
gcc -c exercice6.adb
gnatbind -x exercice6.ali
gnatlink exercice6.ali
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gnatlink: error when calling /Users/alexandretrotel/opt/GNAT/2020/bin/gcc
gnatmake: *** link failed.
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bada%5D+%22-lSystem%22

Comment: That release of GNAT CE **requires** Xcode, not just the Command Line Tools.